# Android app stopped working after adding multiple activities

Tags: java, xml, listview, android-intent

My android application stops working after adding multiple activities. It was working fine when I was handling only one activity i.e. Main Activity. It causes problems after I added other activity and tried to link it with the listview. Possible problem could be with the Intent.

I have 3 other activities named "PActivity", "AActivity" and "DActivity" which I want to show based on the item selected on the listview. All three activities have no code added except the default OnCreate() function which is added by eclipse.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] options = res.getStringArray(R.array.HomeOptions);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    switch (position)
    {
        case 1:
            Intent PIntent = new Intent(this, PActivity.class);
            startActivity(PIntent);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent AIntent = new Intent(this, AActivity.class);
            startActivity(AIntent);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent DIntent = new Intent(this, DActivity.class);
            startActivity(DisallowIntent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#800000"
        android:text="@string/Home"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/HomeOptions" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.MyApplication"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.MyApplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.MyApplication.PActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_p" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.MyApplication.AActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_a" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.MyApplication.DActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_d" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985): Process: com.myapplication, PID: 1985
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapplication/com.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at com.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-01 15:20:34.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     ... 11 more
```

Difference:

Before changing ID of ListView, the last two lines of my android console was:

```
[2014-02-02 14:25:50 - MyApplication] Starting activity com.mobilesecurity.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-02-02 14:25:54 - MyApplication ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.myapplication/.MainActivity }
```

But after changing last message (with ActivityManager) was not shown. I started getting this message after my app started to crash. May be this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
Intent PIntent = new Intent(this, PActivity.class);
startActivity(PIntent);
```

inside `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`

**this** probably is taken as the itemclick listener where in you have to pass the context

try changing it to :

```
Intent PIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PActivity.class);
startActivity(PIntent);
```

and do the same for the rest of the other code snippets too.

**EDIT**

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/listview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/HomeOptions" />
```

change the id to :

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: @Ratatouille: I have edited the question to put LogCat. Please see.

Comment: hi, please have a look at the edit i have made to the answer here. Hope that solves the issue.

Comment: The application still crashes but there is some difference that I have noticed. Kindly look at the new Edit under Difference heading

Comment: i request you to view the log cat again, since the one that has been posted shws that the activity was started. there is something that is missed out in the logcat.